# In contact form 7 , redirection to another page is not working

Tags: wordpress

In my theme, on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://www.example.com/thank-you/';"

is not working

Answer (score 0):

It's still working in older version.You must use deprecated function.Please use below code.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '123' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        ga( 'send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit' );
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Read more:
https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/